# Read dictionary from NSEvent userData

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsevent, nstrackingarea

I have created an `NSTrackingArea` and I am passing a Dictionary in the `userInfo` argument.

```
let trackingData = ["section": 1, "sectionRow": 12, "done": false]
let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(
                            rect: cellView.bounds,
                            options: [NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited, NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways],
                            owner: self,
                            userInfo: trackingData as? [String : AnyObject])
cellView.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
```

This event is successfully received here;

```
override func mouseEntered(event: NSEvent) {
        print("Mouse Entered \(event.userData)")
    }
```

How can I read the values for section etc from userData?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your syntax

```
if let userData = event.trackingArea?.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
  let section = userData["section"] as! Int
}
```

But if you pass the `done` key as `Int` with value `0` or `1` rather than `Bool`, you don't need cast the values of the dictionary because it's distinct `[String:Int]`

```
let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: ... , userInfo: trackingData)
```

and

```
if let userData = event.trackingArea?.userInfo as? [String : Int] {
  let section = event.userData["section"]!
}
```

The optional bindings are for safety, if there are more events to receive and track.

Comment: This is exactly how I was trying to do it. But it gives me this error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'

Comment: `NSTrackingArea` passes the `userInfo` dictionary as `[NSObject : AnyObject]?` therefore you have to cast the dictionary anyway to something more specific. And you have to read also explicitly the tracking area. I updated the answer.

Comment: This just crashes on runtime. EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. xCode gives warning Cast from 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>' to unrelated type.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation reads:

> When handling such an event you can obtain the dictionary by sending `userData` to the `NSEvent` object.

But it seems to be wrong. I never managed to somehow cast or map `NSEvent.userData` (which has type `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`) back to `[String: Any]`. Instead you can do this:

```
override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
    let userInfo = event.trackingArea!.userInfo!
}
```